# JS regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make these expressions into one

```
string.match(/<%[a-z]+%>/g, 'value')

string.match(/&lt;%[a-z]+%&gt;/g, 'value')
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you provide a second parameter (value) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the matches of both expressions, you can do this :

```
 /(<%[a-z]+%>|&lt;%[a-z]+%&gt;)/g
```

Comment: oh right , You can use the or operator in reg , cool. thanks . I'm not that use to reg express , was trying /[<,&lt;]%[a-z]/ etc and it wasn't working for me.